# Unused headers in curl request

Tags: http, go

I'm trying to emulate a curl -X GET with Go, but the server I'm contacting has authentication. I've followed several sites that recommend me to use `r.Header.Add()`, but I can't get my curl call to work.

My curl call that actually returns something:
`curl -X GET https://myserver.com/test/anothertest -H 'x-access-token: a1b2c3d4'`

My code that doesn't return the expected JSON object:

```
func get(api string, headers map[string]string, dataStruct interface{}) (data interface{}, err error) {

    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", api, nil)
    for k, v := range headers {
        req.Header[k] = []string{v}
    }

    currentHeader, _ := httputil.DumpRequestOut(req, true)
    fmt.Println(string(currentHeader))

    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)

    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    data = dataStruct
    err = getJson(api, &data)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    return
}

func main() {
    // args := parse_args(Options{})

    args := Options{Api: "my_server",
    Headers: map[string]string{
        "x-access-token": "a1b2c3d4"}}

    body, _ := get(args.Api, args.Headers, HistoryDecoder{})
    fmt.Println(body)
}
```

Returns:

```
GET /v1pre3/users/current HTTP/1.1
Host: my_server
User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1
X-Access-Token: a1b2c3d4
Accept-Encoding: gzip


map[ResponseStatus:map[Message:Please ensure that valid credentials are being provided for this API call (This request requires authentication but none were provided)] Notifications:[map[Type:error Item:Please ensure that valid credentials are being provided for this API call (This request requires authentication but none were provided)]]]
```

Could anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**edit** adding `curl -v` response

```
* About to connect() to my_server port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 54.210.110.53...
* Connected to my_server (54.210.110.53) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=*.cloud-test.com
*       start date: Feb 28 00:00:00 2018 GMT
*       expire date: Mar 28 12:00:00 2019 GMT
*       common name: *.cloud-test.com
*       issuer: CN=Amazon,OU=Server CA 1B,O=Amazon,C=US
> GET /v1pre3/users/current HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: my_server
> Accept: */*
> x-access-token: a1b2c3d4
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
< Content-Type: application/json
< Date: Tue, 30 Oct 2018 15:49:00 GMT
< Expires: 0
< Pragma: no-cache
< Server:
< x-capabilities: audit
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Request-ID: 2018.10.30.15.49.00.9zHjdeQ-ZEmg2IvzTymnxQ
< transfer-encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
<
* Connection #0 to host my_server left intact
```

Comment: Just looking for differences between the two, in Go you're sending a `Content-Type` (which is invalid because there's no body content to have a type) which you are not sending in your `curl` command. You might find https://mholt.github.io/curl-to-go/ to be helpful.

Comment: One thing you can do to get more info about the request is to use `curl -v ...` (verbose mode) so you can see the full HTTP request and response. The full data set will help you and others here understand why the server is responding differently to the different requests made by your curl and go clients.

Comment: Thanks @Adrian, that site will be a helpful tool for the future. For now it seems to write the same code that I was already using, with the one exception `http.DefaultClient.Do(req)` rather than `client := &http.Client(); client.Do(req)`. It's still failing, even with the change

Comment: @maerics using `curl -v` the only clear difference I can distinguish is that curl keeps my access token lowercase, whereas Go transforms the header into CamelCase: `x-access-token` vs `X-Access-Token`. Could that possibly be the problem? If yes, why is Go transforming it?

Comment: That's not the only difference. There's also the content-type header, as I mentioned in my first comment

Comment: @Adrian Yes, I've removed that line as well. With or without, it doesn't affect the response

Comment: Aside: outgoing requests are subtly different from received requests, so you should use [httputil.DumpRequestOut](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#DumpRequestOut) to dump them.

Comment: @Guus The casing should not, but can be, a problem. You can prevent Go from uppercasing the header key by doing `req.Header[k] = []string{v}`

Comment: @Peter Thanks, I've updated the output accordingly

Comment: @EmilePels Thanks, I've tried it but unfortunately no difference in response

Comment: @Guus Really odd situation you got here. Another obvious difference in the requests you're firing is the user-agent.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how I would be able to fix that. It seems it's Go's HTTP module vs Unix' curl

Comment: I'm also seeing this difference.
Curl: `Accept: */*`
Go HTTP: `Accept-Encoding: gzip`

Comment: You can try adding the `Accept: */*` to your Go request. The `Accept-Encoding` could be a problem but it's unlikely.

Comment: Header names are not case sensitive. So it doesn't really matter what the case is. Or it shouldn't. Your server might have a bug in which it isn't properly reading the X-Access-Token header because it is improperly ignoring the header. In that case the server must be fixed as it is not RFC compliant.

Comment: Thanks @Adrian, @MichaelHampton; I'm starting to suspect the server as well. I'm having a look at other git repos from my colleagues and they're using the same code.

Comment: My colleague just recommended using https://github.com/moul/http2curl;
Adding the following two lines for debugging purposes, I get the following output. `cmd, _ := http2curl.GetCurlCommand(req); fmt.Println(cmd)`: `curl -X 'GET' -H 'x-access-token: a1b2c3d4' 'my_server'`

Comment: The curl output works like a charm when running it directly. I'm at a loss here.

Comment: There are a number of minute differences between them (eg header case, accept-encoding, user-agent) which *should* be irrelevant to the issue but which *could* be causing the issue if the server has a defect. I think at this point the only way to solve it would be to inspect the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of rewriting and debugging, I figured out that `getJson(api, &data)` was *also* making a http.Get call but without headers. Since that took place *after* the request we were discussing, it bypassed all testing and printing.